# Convert XGBoost to PMML in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas, pmml

I have the following dataframe

**train_x:**

```
col1 col2 col3
1      4    89
0.4    1.6  14
100    678  970
```

**train_y:**

```
target
0
0
1
```

I want to convert the xgboost model to pmml as below:

```
from sklearn2pmml import sklearn2pmml, PMMLPipeline
from sklearn_pandas import DataFrameMapper
from xgboost.sklearn import XGBClassifier
pipeline = PMMLPipeline([("mapper", DataFrameMapper([
                                    ([num_features,SimpleImputer(strategy='median')],
                                     [num_features,StandardScaler()],
                                     [cat_features,SimpleImputer(strategy='constant', fill_value='missing')],
                                     [cat_features,OneHotEncoder(sparse=False, handle_unknown='ignore')])
                                     ])),
                         ("classifier", XGBClassifier(**best_params,n_jobs=-1))
])
```

and fit the pipeline

```
pipeline.fit(train_x, train_y)
```

but i get the error below

> TypeError: _build_feature() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given**

Answer (score 0):

This `TypeError` is raised by the `DataFrameMapper.fit` method, because you've specified invalid column-to-transformer mappings.

You should be specifying a list of **two-element** tuples (`[(), ()]`), but right now you're supplying a singleton list, which contains a tuple, which contains **four** lists (`[([], [], [], [])]`).